# Refactoring a phantom server called Swayzee

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

I have made a tool that is pretty useful for me. I have made it open source on [github](https://github.com/bordemof/Swayzee). It is a server that listens for requests and returns an HTML static version of a single page app. It works with a convention that when the title of the page changes means that the new page is rendered.

The way it works is very simple but the actual code its very ugly. Here is the main file of the project. I plan to refactor it soon, and it would be great to hear your ideas to improve modularity, response handling and concurrency.

```js
'use strict';
const
  phantom = require('phantom'),
  cluster = require('cluster'),
  express = require('express'),
  async = require('async'),
  app = express();


var SCRIPT_REGEX = /<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi;
var ASSET_REGEX = /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|woff|\/img|\/css|\/js)/g;
var ESCAPED_REGEX = /escaped_fragment_=/g;
var ERR404_REGEX = /name="prerender-status-code/g;

var ORIGIN = 'http://localhost:8080/';
var pharguments = ["--load-images=false", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--ssl-protocol=tlsv1"];


var processingQueue = [];




phantom.create(function(ph) {

  ph.createPage(function(page) {

    page.open(ORIGIN, function(status) {
      console.log("Swayzee has awakened and is looking for " + ORIGIN + "...");

      app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        console.log("Receiving :", req.url)
        var hasEscapedFragment = req.url.match(ESCAPED_REGEX);
        var isAsset = req.url.match(ASSET_REGEX)

        if (hasEscapedFragment && !isAsset) {
          var hash = '#!' + req.url.split("_escaped_fragment_=")[1];
          processingQueue.push({
            hash: hash,
            response: res,
            page: page,
            running: false
          })
          processNext();
        } else {
          var splited = req.url.split('/');
          var redirect_url = ORIGIN + (splited[splited.length - 2]) + "/" + (splited[splited.length - 1])
          res.redirect(redirect_url);
        }

      });

      app.listen(1333, function() {
        console.log("Swayzee is ready to receive requests.");
      });

    });

    // HANDLE PHANTOM OUTPUT
    page.set('onConsoleMessage', function(msg) {
      // console.log("Phantom Console: " + msg);
      if (msg.indexOf('PEF: ') > -1) {

        var hash = msg.replace('PEF: ', '').split(' -@- ')[0];
        var html = msg.replace('PEF: ', '').split(' -@- ')[1];

        var task = processingQueue.shift();

        if (hash == task.hash) {
          while (SCRIPT_REGEX.test(html)) {
            html = html.replace(SCRIPT_REGEX, "");
          }
          console.log("Response ready for ", hash);

          if (html.match(ERR404_REGEX)) {
            task.response.status(404).send(html);
          } else {
            task.response.status(200).send(html);
          }

          // delete pendingResponses[hash]
        }

      }
    });
  });

}, pharguments);


// FETCH AND RENDER PAGE (RECURSIVE),
var fetchAndRenderPage = function(page, hash) {
  console.log("Swayzee has is now stalking ", hash);
  page.evaluate(function(hash) {
    var previousTitle = document.title;
    var iteration = 0;
    window.location.hash = hash;

    function isRenderReady() {
      // console.log(iteration+") Title : ",previousTitle, ' vs ',document.title);
      if (previousTitle === document.title && iteration < 40) {
        iteration++;
        setTimeout(isRenderReady, 50);
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log("PEF: " + hash + " -@- " + document.documentElement.innerHTML);
          document.title = document.title + ' processed ' + Date.now()
          return;
        }, 900);
      }
    }
    isRenderReady();
  }, function(result) {}, hash);
}

//
var processNext = function() {
  if (processingQueue.length > 0) {
    var task = processingQueue[0];
    if (task.running == false) {
      fetchAndRenderPage(task.page, task.hash);
      task.running = true;
    }

  }
}

// ON EXIT
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log("Closing ");
  require('child_process').spawn('pkill', ['phantomjs']);
  ph.exit();
  process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if I read your code correctly, you're using PhantomJS to scrape a page. But the twist is, you don't just want the static HTML (otherwise, we'd be using a simple GET request), but you want the HTML after all the scripts that potentially influence the page run.

> when the title of the page changes means that the new page is rendered

```
function isRenderReady() {
  // console.log(iteration+") Title : ",previousTitle, ' vs ',document.title);
  if (previousTitle === document.title && iteration < 40) {
    iteration++;
    setTimeout(isRenderReady, 50);
```

A weird choice for checking if the page has loaded. Why not listen for [`DOMContentReady`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)? Or even better, use PhantomJS's [`onLoadFinished`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html) event. You can listen to `onLoadFinished` *then* run `evaluate`.

```
phantom.create(function(ph) {

  ph.createPage(function(page) {

    page.open(ORIGIN, function(status) {
      console.log("Swayzee has awakened and is looking for " + ORIGIN + "...");
```

Also wondering why you'd constrain yourself to one instance of a page. Your queue will only bottleneck your requests. You can always create more page objects. If you want rate limiting, I also suggest you pool up a few instances rather than having just one instance.

Additionally, it appears like you're only after the `page` object. You can abstract all this setup with a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object. That way, you don't delay creating your request handlers.

```
var pagePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  phantom.create(ph => {
    ph.createPage(page => {
      resolve(page);
    }
  }
  // Call reject when create and createPage fails.
});

app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  pagePromise.then(page => {
    // Do stuff to page
  });
});

app.listen(1333, function() {
  console.log("Swayzee is ready to receive requests.");
});
```

If the setup hasn't resolved, the request will still wait. Your server *is* ready to receive requests, it's just not ready to service them until the setup finishes.

```
// Assume createPhantomPage is the same promise creator code above

var tenPagePromises = Array(10).fill(0).map(v => createPhantomPage());

Promise.all(tenPagePromises).then(pages => {
  // all 10 pages are ready
  var page1 = page[0];
});
```

If you plan to spawn multiple instances, you can also use Promises. You can spawn say 10 instances, making that 10 promises, then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to listen if all 10 have resolved. When they all resolve, you have 10 `page` objects to play with.

```
var ASSET_REGEX = /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|woff|\/img|\/css|\/js)/g;
var isAsset = req.url.match(ASSET_REGEX)
```

Instead of managing extensions which can vary for the same thing (like `.jpg` and `.jpeg` for a JPEG image) and managing the match yourself, why not use a [mimetype module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types)? That way, you keep a list of mimetypes and use the module to get the mimetype of the path. *Then* you match.

```
var SCRIPT_REGEX = /<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi;

while (SCRIPT_REGEX.test(html)) {
  html = html.replace(SCRIPT_REGEX, "");
}
```

For simple cases, this is fine. However, this won't be enough to prevent scripts from passing through. There will always be ways to inject scripts into a page. I suggest you look into a parser that adheres to the HTML spec to parse, find and remove remove scripts properly. But again, it's probably overkill.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, the main purpose of this tool is to render the different ajax result states of a page as fast as possible, so if you open a page every time a request arrives that adds opening and initial loading of the page to the final response time. Related to the onLoadFinished, my experience is that not always fulfills the correct state so i think its better to make a strong rule/convention that suits SEO purposes to ensure a correct visualization(maybe im wrong).  The mimetype and the Promise advices suits perfect for this code i think, im going to try to refactor the code including them.

Comment: The next idea is to have multiple instances of a page running so the bottleneck impact can be reduced with concurrency dispatching the request to the different less bussy instances. But i think i must clean this code first. Ty for your effort and wise corrections.

Comment: I have already updated the code to use the mime module, but i have not being able to integrate the Promise pattern. It would be great to extract some of the code into modules. https://github.com/bordemof/Swayzee